# Convert the data frame into pixel image

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to convert the data frame into a pixel image.

1) Solaris lib not recognizing vector as its attribute.

2) Is there an another way for converting data frames into pixel images?

```
fbc_mask = sol.vector.mask.df_to_px_mask(df=cropped_polys_gdf, channels=['footprint', 'boundary', 'contact'], affine_obj=tfm, shape=(tile_size,tile_size), boundary_width=5, boundary_type='inner', contact_spacing=5, meters=True)
AttributeError: module 'solaris' has no attribute 'vector'
```

Answer (score 1):

May you can try to firstly convert your dataframe into the numpy array. In my opinion it's the best solution. For example:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3.0, 4.5]})
df.to_numpy()
```